# Can't determine type for tag<shape

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, dependencies

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#D81B60"/>
</shape>
```

This was working well then all of a sudden started showing the error 'Can't determine type for tag '
        
    '
'

Comment: did you add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` above your code? or where you put this xml file?

Comment: The above tag is inside a <resources> tag which has the specification of the xml encoding, but still it does not recognize the <shape tag

Comment: did you put your xml file in res > drawable ?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the encoding declaration to identify which encoding is used to represent the characters in your document. Since xml file may contain ASCII characters, xml files may (i.e for [XML 1.0 is optional](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) but it is [mandatory for XML 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd)) need to start with one of the following headers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

So add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header in your xml file. e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#D81B60"/>
</shape>
```